# Issues with breaking out of a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, nested-loops

Essentially, when a button is pressed the randomMove() method is called, this is mean't to find a empty square in TicTacToe and then assign an "O" to it, the problem is that it then doesn't break out of the loop as at least two squares turn to "O".

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong but I don't doubt it's a simple solution.

```
 private void randomMove()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
            {
                if (Board[a,i] == "")
                {
                    Board[a,i] = "O";
                    Temp = i + a;
                    compMove(Temp);
                    break;
                }  
            }
        }
    }

    private void compMove(int Temp)
    {
        switch (Temp)
        {
            case 0:
                btn1.Text = "O";
                break;
            case 1:
                btn2.Text = "O";
                break;
            case 2:
                btn3.Text = "O";
                break;
            case 3:
                btn4.Text = "O";
                break;
            case 4:
                btn5.Text = "O";
                break;
            case 5:
                btn6.Text = "O";
                break;
            case 6:
                btn7.Text = "O";
                break;
            case 7:
                btn8.Text = "O";
                break;
            case 8:
                btn9.Text = "O";
                break;
        }
        hasWon();
    }
```

Comment: You have nested loops. Do you mean to only break out of the nested one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I look on the code provided and, if I correctly understand what you want, the *only* thing you need here is a `return`, like this:

```
private void randomMove()
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
            {
                if (Board[a,i] == "")
                {
                    Board[a,i] = "O";
                    Temp = i + a;
                    compMove(Temp);
                    return;
                }  
            }
        }
 }
```

And also it's better to change `compMove` method to something like this, imo (*pseudocode*)

```
   private void compMove(int Temp)
   {
      int buttonIndex = Temp + 1;
      Button btn = FindControl("btn" + buttonIndex) as Button;

      if(btn == null) return;

      btn.Text = "O"; 
      hasWon();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use local variables to break out of the second loop ( with a boolean ). Or you use `goto MyLabel;` and define the label with `MyLabel:`;. When only have a simple method, you could also use return.

```
    Boolean finish = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
        {
            if (Board[a,i] == "")
            {
                Board[a,i] = "O";
                Temp = i + a;
                compMove(Temp);
                finish = true;
                break;
            }  
        }
        if (finish) break;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
        {
            if (Board[a,i] == "")
            {
                Board[a,i] = "O";
                Temp = i + a;
                compMove(Temp);
                goto Finish;
            }  
        }
    }
    Finish: ...
```

Comment: goto is evil...  you can but you shouldn't

Comment: @Muad'Dib But should be faster than using the flag.

Comment: @FelixK. The tag says C#, not GWBASIC or Quickbasic ;)

Comment: @HaLaBi goto is a C# keyword.

Comment: @Felix K. goto is not best practices... lessons learned from Jurassic Park: just because you CAN do a thing, does not mean you SHOULD do a thing

Comment: @Muad'Dib That's right, but when you can do a thing sometimes it's useful. There are some cases where goto is very useful.

Comment: @FelixK. I know it is!!! but as Muad'Dib Said existence of a keyword is something and using it is something else..

Answer (score 1):

You need to break out of both loops when an empty spot was located. Your code only breaks out of the nested one.

Here is one way to do so:

```
private void randomMove()
{
    bool foundEmpty = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
        {
            if (Board[a,i] == "")
            {
                Board[a,i] = "O";
                Temp = i + a;
                compMove(Temp);
                foundEmpty = true;
                break;
            }  
        }

        if (foundEmpty)
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your break statement will only escape the first for loop, you would need to use another break or some other mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to break out from the bigger loop.. alter the code a little to look like this:

```
private void randomMove()
{
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
        {
            if (Board[a,i] == "")
            {
                Board[a,i] = "O";
                Temp = i + a;
                compMove(Temp);
                flag = true;
                break;
            }  
        }
        if (flag)
             break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, I think your button text is not going to update as you'd hoped using your `compMove()` function.

`i` and `a` can never have a value higher than 2, as defined by your loops.

Therefore, the highest value your `compMove()` function will ever receive is 4.

Try changing:

```
Temp = i + a;
compMove(Temp);
```

To this:

```
Temp = (i*3) + a;
compMove(Temp);
```

Comment: Lol! Wow, yeah thanks that is a very very obvious mistake but to be fair I don't think I'd of noticed it, loops confuse me for some reason I think I just need alot more practise with them. Thanks :)